# spring boot error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException datasource

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using the spring boot and my sql. I am gettting the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at com.bookstores.BookstoresApplication.main(BookstoresApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSour``ceProperties.java:224) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:176) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

my code is

```
    server.port=8181
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=oracle
#spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.type=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
#spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query= SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>bookstore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem. Currently you mainly dumped your code and didn't tell much what you are doing. This beviour might lead to answers. But if your problem is complicated, then it usually leads to unanswered questions. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It would be good to nclude where you're putting the mysql driver jar, and how you're running this (standalone or as a war, and if in a war what the container is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have only below properties in application.properties

```
server.port=8181
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

To order to work your jpa properties(`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto & spring.jpa.show-sql=true`), please remove hibernate & jbc and add jpa.(or you need to configure hibernate configuration to work hibernate specific properties to auto create and show sqls)

**Remove**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

**and add**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Your `pom` and `application.properties` seems fine but as seems first your load oracle settings then mysql so jar might be corrupted, try these solutions

1. Try to rebuild the project `(Build > Rebuild Project)` the error disappears.
2. Another cause of this error is a corrupted JAR so delete `.m2 directory` and run `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database), to connect to a database

> You often do not need to specify the `driver-class-name`, since Spring Boot can deduce it for most databases from the `url`.

So remove `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` from the properties file.

Also add/replace with MySQL JDBC driver dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the error is same after removing the driver class name

Answer (score 0):

i added mysql connector jar and my error is resolved but the table is not created in the database?

Comment: How are you trying to create a table? Is it, perhaps, a new question?

Comment: i am using the hibernate for creating the table. My code for the entity is                   {}

Comment: Entity
        public class User {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     private int id;
     private String username;
    
     private String password, firstName, LastName,email,phoneNumber;
     private boolean enable=true;
    // all the getter and setters
    }